# Trying to Deploy a Spring Boot JAR file app to Azure App Service with Maven and Azure on Linux

Tags: azure, spring-boot, maven, azure-appservice

I am getting the following error on mvn azure-webapp:deploy

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.9.1:deploy (default-cli) on project mprsreporting: Status code 403 -> [Help 1]

I am following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/deploy-spring-boot-java-app-with-maven-plugin)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with multiple subscriptions and the maven plug in attempting to deploy on a wrong subscription. Fixed it by changing the default subscription